# NoReverseMatch when trying to generate a URL with slug/pk regex combinations in different urlpatterns lists

Tags: django, django-views

When I load the page that uses the context from GroupDetailView and the template from group_detail.html (the code is below), I get this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /groups/professional/
Reverse for 'create_profile' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'professional', 'noun': 'profile'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['groups\\/(?P<slug>[-\\w]+)/$create_(?P<noun>[-\\w]+)/$']
```

Notice above that the keyword arguments have values and both keys are in the pattern that Django tried.

urls.py

```
from . import views
from profile import views as profile_views

app_name = 'group'

group_patterns = ([
    path('', views.GroupDetailView.as_view(), name='group_detail'),
    re_path(r'^create_(?P<noun>[-\w]+)/$', profile_views.profile_create_view, name='create_profile'),
])

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', include(group_patterns)),
]
```

Notice above that slug and noun are in two different lists. I tried to put slug and noun into the same re_path function and it works fine but I **can't** do that because I need them to stay separated.

views.py

```
class GroupDetailView(DetailView):
    model =  Group
    template_name = group_detail.html

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        group_slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        context['group'] = group_slug
        return context
```

group_detail.html template

```
<a role="button" href="{% url 'group:create_profile' slug=group noun='profile' %}">Create New Profile</a>
```

Is there a way Django can realize that the keyword arguments, in fact, do match the pattern it tries when the slugs/strings are in two different url lists? Or, is there any extra code I can use to make it work? Maybe with the use of RedirectView? The solution to this problem can also be applied to combinations of primary keys with slugs, usernames and UUID's in different lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove `$` from `^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$`. As you can see from your error message, Django transformed your chain of urls into url with 2 string ends - that's  definitely a problem:

```
groups\\/(?P<slug>[-\\w]+)/$create_(?P<noun>[-\\w]+)/$
```

Comment: I was starting to think that Django wasn't capable of what I wanted but your eye caught that extra '$'. Thanks! Knowing this is going to make my app so much better because I plan to use this heavily!